# Move Coins downard in Array AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I'm trying to make an array that creates 4 coins (which I've done), but the problem is I'm trying to move the coins downward, and I can't figure out how to access the array list to move the coins down(commented out lenght[i].y +=4) which doesn't work. The other problem is I want to only create 4 coins, and not 4 coins every frame in the update loop.

Thanks.

```
public class Coin extends Sprite
{
    //..SPRITES
    public static var coinSprite:CoinSprite;

    public var _coins:Array = new Array();
    public var c = new CoinSprite();
    public static var COINCOUNT:int = 4;

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    //##SETUP------------------------------------------------------------------|
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    public function Coin()
    {
        super();
        this.addEventListener(starling.events.Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, stageSetup);
    }

    public function stageSetup(event:Event):void {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, stageSetup);
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------|

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    //##MANAGER----------------------------------------------------------------|
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------|

    public function manager():void {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateCoin);
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------|


    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    //##COINHANDLER------------------------------------------------------------|
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------|

    public function coinHandler():void {

        var length:Number = 4;

        for ( var i:Number = 0; i < length; i++) {
            //length[i].y += 4;
            createCoin();
            c.y = i * 50;
        }

    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------|

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    //##COLLISION||------------------------------------------------------------|
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------|

    public function hitCoinPlayer():void {
        //..cleanup
        if (c.hitTestObject(Player.playerSprite)) {
            c.alpha = 0;
        }
        //..check bounds
        if (c.y >= 1500) {
            c.y = -200;
            c.alpha = 1;
        } 
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------|



    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    //##UPDATE-----------------------------------------------------------------|
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------|

    public function updateCoin(e:Event):void {
        //coinHandler();
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------|

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    //##CREATE COIN------------------------------------------------------------|
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    public function createCoin():void {
        c = new CoinSprite();
        c.x = 305;
        Starling.current.nativeOverlay.addChild(c);
        _coins.push(c);
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
}
```

Comment: I don't see that there is an array involved in the code. The loop itself is not enough.

Comment: I updated the post with the full source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public var _coins:Array = {}; // you need an array to store the coins you've created
public function stageSetup(event:Event):void {
    coinHandler(); //create four coins upon setting up the stage
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, stageSetup); //done setup
}

//other parts of the code are not changed

public function coinHandler():void { // you only need to call this once from ur stagesetup

    var length:Number = 4;

    for ( var i:Number = 0; i < length; i++) {

        createCoin();
        c.y = i * 50;
    }

}

public function updateCoin(e:Event):void {
    moveCoin();
}

public function moveCoin(){
    for ( var i:Number = 0; i < _coins.length; i++) {

        _coins[i].y +=4;
    }
}

public function createCoin():void {
    c = new CoinSprite();
    c.x = 305;
    Starling.current.nativeOverlay.addChild(c);
    _coins.push(c);
}
```

Comment: You should cycle up to `_coins.length` instead of just `length`, one less variable and one more property equal one less entity to manage. Also, arrays are not `{}` but `[]` or `new Array()`.

Comment: Hey @Mc Kevin, thanks for fixing this up for me and making it! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Would this be the proper way to do cleanup for collision? if (_coins[i].hitTestObject(Player.playerSprite)) {
        
        Starling.current.nativeOverlay.removeChild(_coins[i]);
        _coins.splice(i, 1);

           _coins[i].alpha = 0;
       }

Comment: yeah, I guess that should be fine. You don't have to set the alpha to 0 though. That line will not do what you think it will do since you've already spliced the colliding one out ;).